# Como incluir botões a partir de um outro botão no Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Eu tenho uma tabela cujo conteudo vem de um jSON que consiste em uma coluna com um numero, uma com um nome e uma com dois botões, de alteração e exclusão da linha. Quando eu clico no botão para criar uma linha nova ela insere o numero e o nome mas não consigo fazer com que insira os botões.

Esse é a função que eu uso para criar as linhas na tabela

```
$(function(){
$(".row").click(function(){

             var Cdgrupo = $("#Cdgrupo").val();
             var Grupo = $("#Grupo").val();
             var Acao = $("#Acao").val();

             var markup = "<tr><td>" + Cdgrupo + "</td><td>" + Grupo + "</td><td>"+ Acao +"</td></tr>";

             $("table tfoot").append(markup);

         }); 
     });
```

Comment: Mas qual sua dificuldade aí, não é só criar os botões como fez com as **tr** e **td**?

Comment: Então eu estou tentando assim, criando o tr e o td da mesma forma como fiz com os outros dois mas por algum motivo não esta indo, na tabela fica só o espaço reservado para onde eles deveriam estar.

Comment: No caso, os botões estariam nessa variável chamada **Acao**?

Comment: Isso, na variavel Acao

Comment: Tenta pegar o elemento usando apenas **$("#Acao")**

Comment: Como assim? eu ainda estou aprendendo Jquery kkk

Comment: Vc quer pegar o elemento certo? Mas quando você usa **$("Acao").val()**, você está pegando o valor do elemento.

Comment: Ah entendi, vou tentar sem usar o .val então. Os botões que eu estou tentando inserir estão escritos em html, usando tags <a> e <button>, será que da algum problema?

Comment: Acredito que não.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiz um exemplo que você pode tentar implementar. Criei uma função **Incrementa** para ir aumentado os valores do `código` e também ao invés de utilizar **`String`** utilizei [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings) para deixar o código mais enxuto:

```js
$(function() {
  var increme = 0;
  
  function Incrementa() {
    return increme++;
  }
  
  $(".row").on("click", function() {
    Incrementa();
    var Cdgrupo = increme;
    var Grupo = `Grupo ${Cdgrupo}`;
    var btnAlt = `<button>Alterar</button>`;
    var btnExc = `<button>Excluir</button>`;

    var markup = `<tr><td> ${Cdgrupo} </td><td> ${Grupo} </td><td> ${btnAlt} </td><td> ${btnExc} </td></tr>`;

    $("table tfoot").append(markup);

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="row">Adicionar</button>

<table>
  <tfoot></tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda LeAndrade! Então, a linha foi criada mas nas colunas, onde deveriam aparecer os nomes dos dados que eu escrevi (numero e nome) aparece ${Cdgrupo} por exemplo. Os botões também ficaram assim.

Comment: Dei uma adaptada aqui e acabou me ajudando a resolver o problema, agora está funcionando! Obrigado pela ajuda LeAndrade!

Comment: Jóia Gabriel, legal que resolveu. Pode aceitar a resposta para sua pergunta não ficar pendente no site.